# Does anyone read the responses to rejected suggested-edit audits?

Tags: discussion

Some of the audits are so obvious I've started writing cheerful notes in the "other" reason box as I reject the edit. Just wondering if all my literary effort is for naught, or if some poor scutpuppy actually reads the responses.

Comment: @Matt, thanks.  Bummer -- here I was hoping for a "best sarcastic response" contest or something.

Comment: I used to be creative too, then I started typing 'test.............' until I hit enough characters to be a legitimate comment.  Now I just click Vandalism.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "Best Sacrastic Response"... Feature Request?

Comment: I'll +1 this just for the use of `scutpuppy` alone.

Comment: Duplicate on MSE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180853/does-anyone-read-messages-on-review-audits

Comment: If I don't get a notification, I'll never even know to go check.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As [I touched upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208920/is-it-okay-to-write-funny-rejection-messages-for-community-suggested-review-audi) in my answer to a similar question on MSE, the rejection reasons given for a suggested-edit **audit*** is not displayed *anywhere* on the site.

I'm pretty sure the rejection reason (e.g. vandalism/ invalid edit/ custom) isn't even saved into the database, so it *can't* be exposed/ viewed from anywhere.

---

<sup>* This is different to rejection reasons for normal suggested edits, which *are* visible in the review page for that suggested edit.</sup>

Comment: audits are stored: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5018614

Comment: @DanielA.White: I was specifically talking about the rejection reason for a suggested-edit audit. For example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5027214), you can't tell that I rejected the edit as "Vandalism". I'll edit my answer to make that perfectly clear.